# Invalid JSON Path _id.$oid bigquery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, unstructured-data

I have this JSON data in a BigQuery column:

```
SELECT JSON '{"$oid":"123"}'
```

How can I get the `$oid` value?

Expected output:
123

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT JSON_QUERY(JSON '{"$oid":"123"}', '$."$oid"')
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**